# How exactly jQuery Mobile or Sencha Touch hide address bar in iPhone even when page changes?

Tags: javascript, iphone

I know how to hide address bar in general

```
addEventListener("load", function() {
    window.scrollTo(1, 0);
}, false);
```

But I'm trying to hide not show address bar when page changes

jQuery Mobile and Sencha Touch manage to do this.
I know I should be reading the source but I have no idea where to look.

Comment: perhaps they bring in the changes using AJAX - ie not reloading the page - this would keep the address bar hidden

Comment: After researching, you were right. Why not put it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

perhaps they bring in the changes using AJAX - ie not reloading the page - this would keep the address bar hidden

Answer (score 1):

Try this in Sencha Touch 2

```
Ext.application({
    viewport: {
        autoMaximize: true
    }
});
```